# How to get spine animation list with Unity custom editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, spine

Hi I try to create custom editor that automates creating character and also their respective animations.

How do i get spine animations list with unity custom editor ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok i found a solution, this is the answer incase you have same problem.

```
if( Selection.activeGameObject )
    {
        SkeletonAnimator spineScript = Selection.activeGameObject.GetComponent<SkeletonAnimator>();
        if (spineScript == null)
            return;

        SkeletonDataAsset m_skeletonDataAssets = spineScript.SkeletonDataAsset;

        if (m_skeletonDataAssets == null)
            return;

        SkeletonData m_skeletonData = m_skeletonDataAssets.GetSkeletonData(false);

        GUILayout.Label("Animation List");
        foreach (Spine.Animation animation in m_skeletonData.Animations) {
            using (new GUILayout.HorizontalScope()) {
                GUILayout.Label(animation.name);
            }
        }
    }
```